# How can I get all photos from a friends photo stream using FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

This graph API call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<userid>/photos
```

returns all photos that the user has in their photo stream.

I do know how to get photos from a friends album using FQL, but this is not what I want.

How can I accomplish the above graph call in FQL?

Answer (score 0):

You have to look them up out the stream of that user.

```
SELECT post_id, app_data.photo_ids FROM stream WHERE filter_key IN (
SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() AND name = 'Photos'
) AND source_id = me()
```

check out:

stream table https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

stream_filter table https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_filter/